# looping date with statement from database table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

i'm newbie Programmer Codeigniter

i want to show all days from 1 month and give statement from the table of holiday date (i have 46 holiday). i want if holiday, the date show is red.

my controller like this

```
function attendance()
{           
    $data = $this->page();
    $data['this_month'] = date('m');
    $data['this_year']  = date('Y');
    $data['this_day']   = date('d');        
    $this_month = date('m');
    $month = $this->m_date->month($this_month)->row_array();
    $data['day_total'] = $month['day_total'];
    $data['holiday'] = $this->m_date->holiday()->result_array();
    $data['attendance']= $this->m_module->attendance()->result_array();     
    $data['employee']= $this->m_module->employee()->result_array();
    $this->template->display($data['link'],$data);
}
```

this is my view

```
<?php for($m=1; $m <= $day_total; $m++){ ?>
                <?php foreach ($holiday AS $date){ ?>
                    <?php if ($date['tgl'] === date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this_year.'-'.$this_month.'-'.$m))){
                        echo '<th bgcolor="red">'.$m.'</th>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<th bgcolor="">'.$m.'</th>';
                    } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

but when i run in the browser, show like this

[error looping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z8Pv.png)

please help me for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I updated the code**

in your holiday-loop you echo the date in every iteration, try something like this:

```
<?php
 for($m=1; $m <= $day_total; $m++){ 
     $color ="";
     foreach ($holiday AS $date){               
           if ($date['tgl'] === date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this_year.'-'.$this_month.'-'.$m))){
               $color="red";
           }
      }
     echo '<th bgcolor="'. $color  .'">'.$m.'</th>';
  } 
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but a little problem, the date double with holiday. like this 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15 16 17. date 1 and 15 is double.